# How to reduce a tooltip font size in JBossTools

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

How to reduce a tooltip font size in JBossTools because it's too big while I prefer a smaller? Where are those options in settings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences, then under General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts and then under Java you can find "Javadoc display font".

Tip: use filters (marked red on the picture) to find something in preferences - they're really useful.

[image: Content assist font size]